# Having trouble with simple palindrome program

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code a simple c++ program that lets the user know if the word they input is palindrome or not. Example: 'mom' is palindrome.

Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Forward Declaration
string reversed_string(string);


int main(){
    string str;
    string reversed;
    cout << "Enter string to check:\n";
    getline(cin, str);

    reversed = reversed_string(str);

    if(str == reversed){
        cout << str << " is palindrome\n\n";
    }
    else{
        cout << "Not palindrome";
    }
}

string reversed_string(string str){
    string reversed;

    for(int i = int(str.length()); i >= 0; i--){
        reversed += str[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

When I try to input a palindrome word, it always goes to the else statement in my main function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing `-1` for the length. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this is hardly a "typo". The question shows research effort, is clear, and the error may or may not stem from a misunderstanding about the length of a string with relation to its indices, or simply lack of familiarity, but it is a common pitfall and more importantly undefined behaviour rather than an overt compiler error, which warrants an answer flagging this risk, rather than dismissing it as a typo. Moreover, it has attracted such an answer. Do not close. At most I would suggest the title could be made a bit more informative for users searching with a similar issue.

Comment: Just changing `str.length()` to `str.length() - 1` in the posted code will be bugged for empty strings. `int(str.length()) - 1` would be one way.

Answer (score 1):

The last character of a string is at index `len - 1`, not `len`. As per the standard (C++11):

> Returns `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type charT with value charT(), where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.

What that standardese actually means is that, if `pos` is not less than the string length, the function returns a reference to a null character. Hence the first character you're putting *into* your reversed string is the null.

However, you don't really need to reverse the string to find if it's a palindrome, it might be easier to simply use the following (pseudo-code) algorithm:

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    set left to zero
    set right to one less than string length
    while left is less than right:
        if string[left] is not equal to string[right]:
            return false
        add one to left
        subtract one from right
    return true
```

Given you have to process every character to form the reversed string anyway, you may as well use that processing power to just check the characters in the original string. That way, you can exit early if it's not a palindrome.

This will, of course, consider an empty string to be a palindrome, which is arguably correct. If you *don't* think that's correct, simply put a check in up front:

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    if string length is zero:
        return false
    set left to zero
    ... and so on
```

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed ... but you switched over to python half way through your edits :p   (force of habit? :p )

Comment: @Tasos (καλά Χριστούγεννα, by the way, assuming your name attests your heritage, apologies if not), it may *look* like Python but that's only because Python is the ideal pseudo-code language :-) That's why I stated it was an algorithm rather than code. The reason I used pseudo-code is in the likely case this is a classwork assignment or even self-education - in that case, OP will learn more by implementing it themselves. Will clarify.

Comment: hahah. Ευχαριστώ, επίσης! Fair enough. My counter argument would be that a proper example (one explaining away all that `using namespace std;` business for instance) would be more instructive, but yes I do agree somewhat. Btw, shouldn't that "empty" check be `-1` rather than zero?

Comment: @paxdiablo - I should have considered the classroom/assignment factor before posting my response. My bad.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou you're right, deleted. see my previous comment